# Wordpress not recognising correct PHP version for update

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress install on Godaddy that was on PHP4.

I have shifted the Godaddy programming language to PHP 5.2 but the Wordpress update page still shows this error:

> You cannot update because WordPress 3.2.1 requires PHP version 5.2.4 or higher. You are running version 4.4.9.

The Godaddy account says PHP 5.2 is being used.

How can I update Wordpress now as the "Update" button is no longer showing?

Comment: Are you sure the PHP version is correct? Create a file in your document root with `<?php echo phpversion() ?>` and see what it displays

Comment: In addition, you can use `<?php phpinfo() ?>` - good to know for debugging similar issues in the future.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I put the above code in to test the version and it displays that the PHP Version is 4.4 so I can only assume GoDaddy settings and internal account is incorrect. I've double and triple checked and it says the account is running on PHP 5 but I guess it can't be. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Even though GoDaddy may offer PHP5, it is something you have to set in your `.htaccess` file at the root of your site.

Add this to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler cgi-php5 .php
```

**NOTE:** you may not need the `AddType` line, if your site gives a 500 error, then remove that line.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, with or without the initial AddType line?

Comment: see if this helps: http://www.ardamis.com/2009/07/25/upgrading-godaddy-hosting-to-php-5-x-from-php-4-3-11/ I'm no longer on GoDaddy (thank god), so I can't verify.